# PostGIS Similarity between drawn polygon (x,y between [0,1]) and set of buildings (SRID 4326)

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, similarity

I would like to find the set of  buildings (SRID 4326) that are similar to a shape drawn by a user (x,y between 0 to 10)**

Is it possible to do that with PostGIS?

Requirements:

- A polygon drawn by a user on a web interface inside a box : let say x,y coordinates are between 0 and 100)
- A big table containing a list of buildings of a city (polygon geography/SRID 4326 geom attribute)
- The coordinates references are not the same (lat,lng for building and a Cartesian normalized x,y coordinates for the drawn polygon)
- It should be scale / rotation independent

**Update:**
I think we need to compute a kind of ["turning function"](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Edph/papers/ACHKM-TPAMI-91.pdf) for each polygon and then computing a L2 distance for measuring similarity between 2 polygons.  Turning function seems to be invariant to rotation/scaling/translation.

So, next step: How can I compute a "turning function" in PostGIS?

Comment: Maybe you could use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html but the function requires that you normalize the geometries first. Normalizing the coordinate systems should be simple but scale/rotation independency feels tricky.

Comment: @user30184 I am curious:  how would you normalize in PostGis a building/polygon from lat/lng/srid 4236 coordinates into a coordinate reference x,y between 0 and 100 (a boundingbox)?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22166032/10134441